# How to make this boolean statement false through Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have to use reflection.

In my ATM class I have two variables:

```
   private int userBalance = 100;
   private int moneyInMachine = 100000;
```

I would like to withdraw an unlimited amount of money.

Here is the ATM's withdraw function:

```
private void widthdrawAmount(int n) {
    if (this.userBalance - n < 0 || this.moneyInMachine - n < 0) {
       // You can not pull money out.
    }

    this.updateScreen();
}
```

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to take this boolea statement false.

Comment: You can't do this using reflection since that's compiled code. Using reflection you only can call methods, change field values etc. but not change the code itself. The only way to use reflection here would be to alter `userBalance` and `moneyInMachine` to be at least equal to `n`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Field userBalance = myAtm.getClass().getDeclaredField("userBalance");
userBalance.setAccessible(true);
userBalance.set(myAtm, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

Field moneyInMachine = myAtm.getClass().getDeclaredField("moneyInMachine");
moneyInMachine.setAccessible(true);
moneyInMachine.set(myAtm, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: Wow, someone is gonna get rich, LOL.

Answer (score 1):

You can only change the values of the fields, not the statements of your code.

This code:

```
public static class ATM {
  private int userBalance = 100;
  private int moneyInMachine = 100000;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    ATM a = new ATM();
    Field balanceField = ATM.class.getDeclaredField("userBalance");
    balanceField.setAccessible(true);
    balanceField.set(a, 123456);
    System.out.println(a.userBalance);
  }
}
```

prints

`123456`

This means that you can change the value of even private variables using reflection.